# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function...неизвестно почему?

Tags: php

Пол дня пытаюсь найти причину **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Head() in...**

Функция Head() выводит всё что между тегами **head** и на других страницах с другими скриптами работает всё шикарно, а тут не пойму в чём дело.

Есть вот такой JS скрипт, он передаёт параметр **coin** в пхп-файл

```
function plusCoinGoodsItem(coin){
    alert(coin);  
 $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'../page/cart_page.php',
      data:{plusCoinGoodsItem:coin},
      success:function(data){
        $(".coinGoodsCartInd").html(data);
      }
 });
}
```

А в пхп-файле вот это:

```
<?
Head();
$plusCoinGoodsItem = $_POST['plusCoinGoodsItem'];
echo $plusCoinGoodsItem;
?>

ИТОГ - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function..
```

Comment: Для того чтобы в РНР воспользоваться функцией, её надо сначала задать. или хотя бы подключить файл, в котором она задана

Comment: Переписал структура проекта и указал это в вопросе. Сможете подсказать в чём дело? Сталкиваюсь с этим впервые.

Comment: всем конечно сразу стало понятно, откда здесь должна взяться функция header()

Comment: Какая функция header(), О чём вы? Выдаются ошибки, что не видать подключаемых файлов мне. А почему....ломаю голову и интернет. Нашёл решение вместо **include** использовать **require**....безрезультатно.

Comment: а ты вопрос целиком переписал. вообще-то тут так не делают. На, просвещайся, писатель: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths И в следующий раз пиши ошибку целиком. Если уж сам ее прочесть не можешь, то хотя бы умные люди растолкуют

Answer (score 0):

Видимо вы создали функцию Head в другом файле и забыли подключить его.

Пример подключения другого файла:

**vars.php**

```php
<?php

$color = 'зеленое';
$fruit = 'яблоко';

?>
```

**test.php**

```php
<?php

echo "Одно $color $fruit"; // Одно

include 'vars.php';

echo "Одно $color $fruit"; // Одно зеленое яблоко

?>
```

Помимо **include** также существует **require**

> require аналогично include, за исключением того, что при ошибке он
> также выдаст фатальную ошибку уровня E_COMPILE_ERROR. Другими словами,
> он остановит выполнение скрипта, тогда как include только выдал бы
> предупреждение E_WARNING, которое позволило бы скрипту продолжить
> выполнение.

Источники:

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php

Comment: Нет не о том мы. У меня всё подключено, сейчас перепишу вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос изменил, сможет кто помощь советом?

Comment: @Кариот ваши файлы php находятся в одной папке на сервере?

Comment: Ну да, шаблонные файлы лежат в одной папке - template